# Next.js and Redux-Observable. Handle requests in getInitialProps

Tags: ajax, redux, rxjs, redux-observable, next.js

I'm looking for example how can I use `getInitialProps` hook of **Next.js** to handle **redux-observable** ajax epics. Is it even possible?

In other words - how to utilize this in `getInitialProps` :

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax';

// action creators
const fetchUser = username => ({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: username });
const fetchUserFulfilled = payload => ({ type: FETCH_USER_FULFILLED, payload });

// epic
const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${action.payload}`)
        .map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
    );
```

... so I can fetch initial data on server.

Docs for [getInitialProps](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly you want to dispatch actions from `getInitialProps` and make sure that those actions were completed so then the render can happen. Take a look at this lib https://github.com/mquintal/next-redux-observable it might help.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Please share some explanation of how this library work etc. otherwise recommendation is just a comment :)

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** My original answer didn't make it clear enough that what I meant is that it is not normally possible, nor idiomatic, to dispatch an action inside a component (or getInitialProps) and provide some sort of callback to be notified when it completes.

Instead, typically you would dispatch an action, your Epics would deal with it (perform side effects) then they would themselves dispatch other actions to trigger state changes in Redux. Your components would re-render only based on state changes to the Redux store. This is how it was designed, for better or worse.

To those who have down-voted due to that fact, I'm sorry, that's just not what Redux Observable was designed to do. Redux Observable was not designed with Next.js in mind. If you're using it and Redux just as a way to fetch data, it's probably more ceremony than it's worth vs. just calls to `fetch()`.

That said, software is almost always malleable hehe. It's technically *possible* to make something work, even if it's not what RO intended. I do not recommend it, though. RO was not intended for ahead-of-time page rendering sort of things, instead meant for complex client-side interactions. You can certainly do both though! Use a regular fetch() or other AJAX utility inside your getInitialProps, then defer to RO for the complex client-side requirements, if applicable.

Either way, there's now an example in the [Next.js repo of how someone else](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/c0724cac821a98489f5cbb48ec5471e12177c0ec/examples/with-redux-observable/pages/index.js#L11-L20) approached it, but I don't personally advocate that approach.

If I had to do it, here's mine:

```
/* 1. Add something like this to your root reducer
*************************************************/
function lastActionType(state = null, action) {
  // If you wanted to, you could store the entire action including the payload,
  // but if you ever have actions which have a large payload, it would prevent
  // it from being garbage collected until the next action was dispatched.
  return action.type;
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  lastActionType, // <-- add this
  ...otherReducers,
});

/* 2. Create a utility to listen for an action
*************************************************/
function waitForAction(store, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
      const state = store.getState();
      if (state.lastActionType === options.fulfilled.type) {
        unsubscribe();
        const value = options.fulfilled.selector(state);
        resolve(value);
      } else if (state.lastActionType === options.rejected.type) {
        unsubscribe();
        const value = options.rejected.selector(state);
        reject(value);
      }
    });
  });
}

/* 3. Use the utility
*************************************************/
async function getInitialProps() {
  // Kick it off
  store.dispatch(fetchUser('user123'));

  try {
    // Wait for it
    const user = await waitForAction(store, {
      fulfilled: {
        type: FETCH_USER_FULFILLED,
        selector: (state) => {
          // Some sort of state selector for looking up users
          return state.user;
        },
      },
      // If you want to have error handling, this might be how you'd do it too.
      rejected: {
        type: FETCH_USER_REJECTED,
        selector: (state) => {
          // Some sort of state selector for errors
          return state.userError;
        },
      },
    });

    return {
      user,
      ...otherPropsYouHave,
    };
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle errors in some way
  }
}
```

---

To use redux-observable with React your UI component will dispatch plain actions that your Epics will then listen and respond to. So your components have no direct knowledge of redux-observable--they just dispatch actions and connect to the store to receive state changes.

Here's a simple JSBin example from the docs: https://jsbin.com/jexomi/edit?js,output

```
const App = ({ isPinging, ping }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>is pinging: {isPinging.toString()}</h1>
    <button onClick={ping}>Start PING</button>
  </div>
);

export default connect(
  ({ isPinging }) => ({ isPinging }),
  { ping }
)(App);
```

There's also a slightly more complex example here: https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/tree/master/examples/redux-observable-shopping-cart

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's unfortunately not an answer to my question. I know how to set actions that my epics will listen to, my question is can I (somehow) use them with Next.js to fetch initial data on the server. Here is the [description of static method that does that in Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)

Comment: [An example of fetching data with Promises](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/data-fetch/pages/index.js)

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm where you were at now.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it more clear, and include an approach if desired.